# Spritekit how to make a claw machine game (swift)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to have a claw on top of a screen, then pressing a button would drop the claw down, then press it again would do the grab animation.

Right now I can spawn the objects on the bottom of the screen for the claw to grab but I have no idea how to implement the claw part. How does "grabbing" work in spritekit

can someone help or point me to tutorials that similar to a claw machine game?

Comment: If you need a tutorial, look for one for yourself.  Asking for a tutorial is not a valid topic here.

Comment: uh maybe if there's a tutorial that can be found while searching then I didn't need to go on here to ask obviously....plus I'm asking if anyone know how to implement this OR know an existing tutorial that I haven't found, then please do point it out...don't be a negative Tomato here

Comment: imo perfectly decent question. tutorials go over how to do one specific thing, and rarely teach the underlying principles, thus leaving many out in the cold

Comment: I would suggest using some sort of state (variable) to capture the item.. like `isCaptured = true`, versus trying to use physics... then it is a matter of moving the item along the same axis as the claw at the same right (claw moves up 1 pixel, item moves up 1 pixel).